# Product expiry alert in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have installed `product_expiry` module, and enabled access right `Manage Lots / Serial Numbers` and `A warning can be set on a product or a customer (Sale)` for `Admin`.
 I created a Lot and Inventory adjustment for a product. In the lot, entered `Best before data, End of life date, Removal date and Alert date`.[image]

Question is, where the expiry alert will occur?
Do I need to create any CRON job for it?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that by "expiry alert", you mean "when the set alert date is over, then someone is told the product/lot is about to reach end of life/alert date/... (a message is sent to an user, or an email is sent, or a warning is displayed when the user opens the form for the product/lot or try to sell the product/lot)".

### Short answer :

The access rights you've set aren't even related to `product_expiry` per se and do not do trigger any expiry alert based on the fields you've set. Also, `product_expiry` code doesn't contain anything that could look like an expiry alert.

You have to set cron/automated actions to alert users when some products are about to expire.

Since I do not use this module, here is

### How I've figured it :

First I checked the code at https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/10.0/addons/product_expiry. Basically, the only thing the `product_expiry` module do is adding the date fields you've entered.

Then I checked the models the `product_expiry` models extend, and I didn't find anything who could trigger an expiry alert.

At that point, I wondered what the `A warning can be set on a product or a customer (Sale)` rule would do at all (I've done it for `Manage Lots / Serial Numbers` aswell, and didn't find anything interesting), so I ran this in odoo 10 root directory:

```
find . -exec grep -Hn 'A warning can be set' {} 2> /dev/null \;
```

This found `A warning can be set on a product or a customer (Sale)` in the `sale` module.

After a quick reading of `sale` code, it turned out that the only thing the access you've granted to admin only allows him to access some fields on `res_partner` and `sale` views, in the Internal Notes/Description tab, more precisely the `sale_warn` and `sale_warn_msg` (in the `res.partner`form) and `sale_line_warn` and `sale_line_warn_msg` (`product.template` form).

These fields are then used by [this piece of code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L229) and [that piece of code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L862). The only thing they do, is returning a `warning` action when some conditions are met (the `product_id` for the current `sale.order.line` is changed by the current user to a `product.template`for which `sale_line_warn`, `sale_line_warn_msg` fields are set).

While this is an interesting feature, it's not related at all to the `product_expiry` module.

If you want to send 'expiry alerts', then you indeed have to set up some cron/automated actions rules to do so. Again, since I do not use this module, I could be wrong, but it's very unlikely.